# Remove '0' Number from time 9:00 AM

Tags: c#

I have time format like 9:00AM - 10:00AM.

```
string startTime = "9:00AM";
string endTime = "10:00AM";
```

I want to display it like `9-10 AM`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: what will be output if starttime="9:00AM" and endTime = "10:00PM"?

Comment: then it will be 9AM-10PM.
In short want to remove 0 from time.

Comment: You should probably first change the Format of starttime and endtime to a TimeSpan

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", starttime.Remove(starttime.IndexOf(':'),3), Endtime.Remove(Endtime.IndexOf(':'),3));` (dumb solution if you can live with "9AM-10AM") - Better work on DateTime/DateTimeOffset

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have datetime, use datetime.ToString("HH");
If you don't, you can also write like that (remove AM before doing it)

```
Convert.ToDateTime(starttime).ToString("HH");
```

There are also easier ways to do it if you have fixed numbers;

```
starttime.Replace(":00","")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did it by doing this starttime.Replace(":00", ""). It helped me. :)

Comment: @NiraliAkabari in any case you should use DateTime or TimeSpan to represent times like suggested, that is why those classes exist.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your times

```
var sdt = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var edt = ...
```

Compare the meridian designators or check if the start is before 12 and the end is after:

```
if(sdt.Hour < 12 && edt.Hour >= 12)
```

If the times are in the same day half, use format `${sdt:h}-{edt:htt}"`

If the times are in different day halves use format `${sdt:htt}-{edt:htt}"`

Answer (score -1):

```
string starttime = "9:00AM";
string Endtime = "10:00AM";

starttime = starttime.Replace(":00AM","");
Endtime  = Endtime.Replace(":00","");

var result = starttime + "-" + Endtime;
```

But i think you must change the Format of starttime and endtime to a TimeSpan or DateTime